# Doxygen command

Tags: doxygen

I am researching Doxygen and trying to collect documentation.
There are lines of code in the original documentation

```
/// Get the current running request.
/// \sq{Type,         Synchronous function,
///     Notification, none (synchronous function)}
```

and there is such a representation in the Doxygen source document.

```
Get the current running request. 
     _____________________________________________
    | Type          |  Synchronous function       |
    |_______________|_____________________________|
    | Notification  |  none (synchronous function)|
    |_______________|_____________________________|
```

If I collect the documentation myself from these files - I have a whole line

```
Get the current running request. \sq{Type, Synchronous function, Notification, none (synchronous function)}
```

What am I doing wrong, or what settings do I need to set for this in order to get a view in the form of a table?
I read the documentation for Doxygen, but there is no description of the \sq command

Perhaps someone will tell me with what commands using the above text i can get a view in the form of the table shown above?

Comment: Did you check the configuration of the running process for custom macros?

Comment: I don't know anything about custom macros, i used the default Doxygen settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the problem with a default settings file one will get the warning:

```
 warning: Found unknown command '\sq'
```

so in the original code you probably will have an `ALIASES` (see the documentation: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases) where the `sq` command is defined with 4 arguments.

The content of this `sq` command has to be defined by the user (probably here something with a table can be done).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to get the desired result by applying following definition:`ALIASES += sq{4}="<table class=\"doxtable\"><tr><td>\1 </td><td>\2  </td></tr><tr><td>\3 </td><td>\4  </td></tr></table>"`